# Unable to access wampserver homepage as displaying IIS homepage

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, iis, wamp

In my OS, i have activated both windows IIS server (for run asp files) and Wampserver. in the first instance i faced to a problem as both server running on same port. the error occured as this ;

"The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction"

Then I changed the port in httpd.conf (in wamp > apache > httpd.conf) as "Listen 80" into "Listen 8080". then both servers worked well.

then  i did these things.

1. run asp file (as a test)
2. extract phpmyadmin folder in to wwwroot folder in C:/inetpub (but couldn't open the phpmyadmin).
3. Then i needed to create database in IIS server. i searched the IIS manager window and tried to create a connection through the "connection strings" option.

   in the form I put "localhost" as the server, and name for database. then ok.

   then again tried to open phpmyadmin by starting IIS server. (failed)
4. removed the connection string.

Then i stoped the IIS and start the wamp, goto localhost. but it directs for the IIS home page. (ports not changed) Then I restart the laptop and try again. (failed - IIS home page appeared)

Then I did these things.

1. change the port in httpf.conf into 80 and saved it. restart the laptop and try again to run localhost through the wamp. (server not found appeared)
2. reset the port as 8080 in  httpd.conf, saved. try again. (failed : IIS home page appeared)
3. i deactivated the IIS server through the "windows features on off".then tried to open localhost wamp home page through the task bar icon. again it directs for IIS home page.
4. I removed the inetpub directory form the C drive and try again. again it directs for IIS home page.

Now I am unable to access the localhost or phpmyadmin. I have mentioned everything what i have done before this thing was happened. please explain what can be the reason for this and give me the solution for start phpmyadmin through the wamp server.

Comment: Now the browser displays a problem loading page when click on wamp > localhost. (wampmanager already activated)

Comment: I reinstalled the wampserver, then opened the localhost. then it opens well. but the problem was cannot access the phpMyAdmin. it gives following error;   " MySQL said: Documentation
#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need both types of web server running? It seems to me that if you need support for both PHP and ASP, then you should just use IIS as standalone? This avoids the need for messy configuration of ports, page links etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the port number that WAMPServer's Apache is Listening on then you have to use that port number when you try and run anything against that Apache. Browsers default to port 80, but if you want to get to any other port you have to add it to the URL manually.

So you have to use

```
localhost:8080   
localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

When you leave the non standard port number off the url you are defaulting to port 80 and IIS is listening on port 80.

Comment: Thanks Riggs.. i manually changed the ports. as like this.  ISS  - port 80 (default) , Xampp - port 81 and  Wamp - port 8080. Now can run each servers at the same time..

Answer (score 0):

> extract phpmyadmin folder in to wwwroot folder in C:/inetpub (but couldn't open the phpmyadmin).

You have tried to install PHPmyadmin, on your IIS instance, which you are using to run ASP pages only. Unless you have configured IIS to run PHP then you won't be able to run phpmyadmin from the `inetpub` directory.

You should instead run phpmyadmin from your Apache `htdocs` or `www` or `public_html` folder. As your WAMP (Windows Apache Mysql PHP) is configured to run PHP.

Realistically, unless you have a specific need for both web servers running, then you should choose just one configuration which suits your needs best.

Based on what you've written in your question. There are these two options. (I would personally recommend number one)

1. Use IIS as your only web server instance. Install Mysql and PHP separately, and [configure IIS to run PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php). Then you will be able to have phpmyadmin to manage your mysql databases, and run ASP pages without a fuss.
2. Use WAMP as your only instance and install [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/). This allows you to run ASP pages on Apache.